# perl to modify clipboard before pasting

Tags: perl

Every time I copy some text in the Kindle app, the content copied is always appended with something extra like `(Kindle Location 155). Icon Books. Kindle Edition.` and blank lines.

I want to remove these irrelevant information before pasting it somewhere else.
e.g. Here's one of the possible input from clipboard mimicking the copying result from Kindle app (mind the `space` character at the end of the `Kindle Edition.`):

```
without

Mark Forsyth. The Etymologicon (Kindle Location 4047). Icon Books. Kindle Edition.
```

The expected output to clipboard should be just (blank lines should also be removed):

```
without
```

I've searched and tried something like this one using grep, and it works:
`pbpaste | grep -v -e'Kindle Edition. $' -e '^\s+$' | pbcopy`

In perl, is there something similar to achieve the same thing? like this:

`pbpaste | perl -Mutf8::all -E’$_ =~ s/Kindle Edition. $|^\s+$//mg; print $_' | pbcopy`

This one doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Note that you don't want to use `-E` in resusable code since it's not forward compatible. It defies the feature system which is designed to prevent upgrades from breaking existing code. Use `-M5.014` or whatever version is approriate instead. (It's not needed at all here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't read anything. Your patterns has errors. And it looks like you're trying to remove stuff no matter where it is in the file instead of just at the end.

`-n` (implied by `-p`) reads the input a line at a time, executing the program for each line. But the simplest way to delete matches only if they are at the end of the file is to read the entire input at once. `-0777` will define a line to be the entire file, so we'll use that.

```sh
pbpaste | perl -0777pe's/^\n.* Kindle Edition\.\s*\z//mg' | pbcopy
```

Test:

```
$ cat a; echo END
foo

bar

Mark Forsyth. The Etymologicon (Kindle Location 4047). Icon Books. Kindle Edition.
END

$ perl -0777pe's/^\n.* Kindle Edition\.\s*\z//mg' a; echo END
foo

bar
END
```

Comment: I had taken your pattern being correct for granted. Updated my answer.

Comment: I have added an example of possible input.

Comment: And my solution works with that example. Still, I've made some further improvements.

Comment: It seems to miss a space after `Kindle Edition\.` After adding a space, it works perfectly.  `pbpaste | perl -0777pe's/^\n.* Kindle Edition\. \n?\z//mg' | pbcopy` Could you update the answer?

Comment: The appended content by the Kindle app when copying text always ends with a space as of 2021.09.12.